# Ошибка при записи данных в mysql

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

При регистрации пользователя в боте вк выдает ошибку: can't concat list to bytes

```
                    if mess == "/рег":

                            connection = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, db=db, charset='utf8mb4',
                                                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
                            try:
                                cursor = connection.cursor()
                                param = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = %s'
                                result = cursor.execute(param, event.message.from_id)
                                if result != 0:
                                    vk.method("messages.send",
                                              {"from_id": user_id, "peer_id": peer_id, "disable_mentions": 1,
                                               "message": "❌" + saying_name + ", ты уже регистрировался ранее!",
                                               "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                                else:
                                    sql = "SELECT * FROM `users"
                                    cursor.execute(sql)

                                    sql = 'INSERT INTO users (userid, balans)' \
                                      + ' values (%s, %s)'
                                    cursor.execute(sql, (event.message.from_id, 0))

                                    connection.commit()
                                    vk.method("messages.send",
                                              {"from_id": user_id, "peer_id": peer_id, "disable_mentions": 1,
                                               "message": "✅" + saying_name + ", успешная регистрация!",
                                               "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})

                            finally:
                                   connection.close()
```

Comment: В какой строке?

Comment: Где insert into

Comment: Можно текст ошибки?)

Comment: can't concat list to bytes